# Swift - how to change values of one key in an array of dictionaries using another array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of 3 dictionaries which looks something like this:

```
array1 = [["measure1":"90", "measure2":"200","measure3":"23", "measure4":"190"],["measure1":"60", "measure2":"340","measure3":"531", "measure4":"2000"],["measure1":"210", "measure2":"2","measure3":"12", "measure4":"743"]]
```

Then I also have an array like this:

```
array2 = ["10","20","30"]
```

I am trying to replace all the values of "measure4" in the array of dictionaries with the values in array2, in order (i.e. the first "measure4" becomes "10", the second "20" etc)

It feels like the answer should be simple, but i've been trying various different for in loops and nothing brings out the correct array of dictionaries, which should look like this:

```
array1 = [["measure1":"90", "measure2":"200","measure3":"23", "measure4":"10"],["measure1":"60", "measure2":"340","measure3":"531", "measure4":"20"],["measure1":"210", "measure2":"2","measure3":"12", "measure4":"30"]]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some of the code you tried and the problems you ran into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array1[0]["measure4"]? = array2[0]
array1[1]["measure4"]? = array2[1]
array1[2]["measure4"]? = array2[2]
```

or as a loop

```
for i in 0..<min(array1.count, array2.count) {
    array1[i]["measure4"]? = array2[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim - i like the for loop solution, but it gives me the correct answer 3 times - is there a way of just getting one array of dictionaries?

Comment: @PlanB, when I add a `print(array1)` after the for loop I see one array with 3 dictionaries so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Joakim - yes sorry, was printing inside the for loop - thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i, x) in array2.enumerated() {
    array1[i]["measure4"] = x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let new = array1.enumerated().reduce([[String: String]](), { acc, elemEnumerated in
    var mutableDict = elemEnumerated.element
    mutableDict["measure4"] = array2[elemEnumerated.offset]
    return acc + [mutableDict]
})
```